# query JSON array column in mysql into rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table with data like

```
| user_id   | favorite_foods                        |
|---------  |-------------------------------------- |
| user1     | ["milk","cake"]                       |
| user2     | null                                  |
| user3     | ["cake","hotdogs"]                    |
| user4     | ["cheese","apples","cake","hotdogs"]  |
```

And I'd like to extract the data from arrays into a more normalized form like

```
| user1     | milk      |
| user1     | cake      |
| user2     | null      |
| user3     | cake      |
| user3     | hotdogs   |
| user4     | cheese    |
| user4     | apples    |
| user4     | cake      |
| user4     | hotdogs   |
```

It seems like if this were possible, it would be with `JSON_EXTRACT` but I don't see any documentation on whether it is possible to output one row per path expression result, such that other non-JSON columns are output beside the path result.

Comment: Where do you see JSON?

Comment: `["milk","cake"]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/02/a-beginners-guide-to-json-the-data-format-for-the-internet/?cb=1&_ga=2.147627319.1078370399.1654009084-2123733468.1626897298

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? The preferred way to do this is with [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html).

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks for the helpful link. But I promise you that arrays are a valid JSON type, both in general and in mysql. In your browser console, try `JSON.stringify(["foo","bar"]);`

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks! Looking at that documentation, I don't see how you could "join" based on just the column's placement within a row. Which is to say, I need it to be "user1 : cake; user1 : milk" but looking at JSON_TABLE, it seems like I can't treat that json table as a "member" of the given row. I'll keep reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select user_id, j.food from ihaveatablewithdatalike 
cross join json_table(favorite_foods, '$[*]' columns ( 
  food varchar(20) path '$')) as j;

+---------+---------+
| user_id | food    |
+---------+---------+
| user1   | milk    |
| user1   | cake    |
| user3   | cake    |
| user3   | hotdogs |
| user4   | cheese  |
| user4   | apples  |
| user4   | cake    |
| user4   | hotdogs |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I keep hitting the same syntax error, and assumed it was because I didn't have the target json column as actual JSON type, but eventually realized it was because my local test env wasn't on mysql 8.0. Durp. Testing on 8.0 worked, but column was empty, turns out that was because field length needed to be longer. Once I straightened that out, this was what I needed. Thank you!